# Access an HIVE table with pyspark .py file

Tags: apache-spark, hive, pyspark, google-cloud-platform

I get data from an sql table using this code when I run in the pyspark terminal on a GCP machine

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("appName").getOrCreate()
sc = spark.sparkContext

from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

df= sqlContext.sql('select * from mytable limit 100')
print 'number of rows = ', df.count()
```

It works when the code is copied and pasted on the pyspark terminal window. But It gives this error when the file is run as `.py` from terminal.

```
19/01/21 03:38:43 INFO spark.SparkContext: Running Spark version 2.2.1
19/01/21 03:38:43 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
19/01/21 03:38:43 INFO spark.SparkContext: Submitted application: appName
19/01/21 03:38:43 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: xxxxxxx
19/01/21 03:38:43 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: xxxxxxx
19/01/21 03:38:43 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to: 
19/01/21 03:38:43 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to: 
19/01/21 03:38:43 INFO spark.SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(xxxxxxx); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(xxxxxxx); groups with modify permissions: Set()
19/01/21 03:38:44 INFO util.Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 00000.
19/01/21 03:38:44 INFO spark.SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
19/01/21 03:38:44 INFO spark.SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster
19/01/21 03:38:44 INFO storage.BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Using org.apache.spark.storage.DefaultTopologyMapper for getting topology information
19/01/21 03:38:44 INFO storage.BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: BlockManagerMasterEndpoint up
19/01/21 03:38:44 INFO storage.DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at /tmp/blockmgr-bdcf00db-e6fc-4a6f-a64d-59def40ca89c
19/01/21 03:38:44 INFO memory.MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 4.3 GB
19/01/21 03:38:44 INFO spark.SparkEnv: Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
19/01/21 03:38:44 INFO util.log: Logging initialized @3180ms
19/01/21 03:38:44 INFO server.Server: jetty-9.3.z-SNAPSHOT
19/01/21 03:38:44 INFO server.Server: Started @3277ms
19/01/21 03:38:44 WARN util.Utils: Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port 4040. Attempting port 4041.
19/01/21 03:38:44 WARN util.Utils: Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port 4041. Attempting port 4042.
19/01/21 03:38:44 WARN util.Utils: Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port 4042. Attempting port 4043.
19/01/21 03:38:44 WARN util.Utils: Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port 4043. Attempting port 4044.
19/01/21 03:38:44 WARN util.Utils: Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port 4044. Attempting port 4045.
19/01/21 03:38:44 WARN util.Utils: Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port 4045. Attempting port 4046.
19/01/21 03:38:44 WARN util.Utils: Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port 4046. Attempting port 4047.
19/01/21 03:38:44 WARN util.Utils: Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port 4047. Attempting port 4048.
19/01/21 03:38:44 WARN util.Utils: Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port 4048. Attempting port 4049.
19/01/21 03:38:44 INFO server.AbstractConnector: Started ServerConnector@aaa850a{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:0000}
19/01/21 03:38:44 INFO util.Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 0000.
19/01/21 03:38:44 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@eqqwe23231q2w{/jobs,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
19/01/21 03:38:44 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@eqqwe23231q2w{/jobs/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
19/01/21 03:38:44 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@eqqwe23231q2w{/jobs/job,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
19/01/21 03:38:44 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@eqqwe23231q2w{/jobs/job/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
19/01/21 03:38:44 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@eqqwe23231q2w{/stages,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
19/01/21 03:38:44 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@eqqwe23231q2w{/stages/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
19/01/21 03:38:44 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@eqqwe23231q2w{/stages/stage,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
19/01/21 03:38:44 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@eqqwe23231q2w{/stages/stage/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
19/01/21 03:38:44 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@eqqwe23231q2w{/stages/pool,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
19/01/21 03:38:44 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@eqqwe23231q2w{/stages/pool/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
19/01/21 03:38:44 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@eqqwe23231q2w{/storage,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
19/01/21 03:38:44 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@eqqwe23231q2w{/storage/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
19/01/21 03:38:44 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@eqqwe23231q2w{/storage/rdd,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
19/01/21 03:38:44 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@eqqwe23231q2w{/storage/rdd/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
19/01/21 03:38:44 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@eqqwe23231q2w{/environment,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
19/01/21 03:38:44 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@eqqwe23231q2w{/environment/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
19/01/21 03:38:44 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@eqqwe23231q2w{/executors,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
19/01/21 03:38:44 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@eqqwe23231q2w{/executors/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
19/01/21 03:38:44 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@eqqwe23231q2w{/executors/threadDump,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
19/01/21 03:38:44 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@eqqwe23231q2w{/executors/threadDump/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
19/01/21 03:38:44 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@eqqwe23231q2w{/static,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
19/01/21 03:38:44 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@eqqwe23231q2w{/,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
19/01/21 03:38:44 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@eqqwe23231q2w{/api,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
19/01/21 03:38:44 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@eqqwe23231q2w{/jobs/job/kill,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
19/01/21 03:38:44 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@eqqwe23231q2w{/stages/stage/kill,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
19/01/21 03:38:44 INFO ui.SparkUI: Bound SparkUI to 0.0.0.0, and started at http://00.00.00.00:0000
19/01/21 03:38:44 INFO util.Utils: Using initial executors = 8, max of spark.dynamicAllocation.initialExecutors, spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors and spark.executor.instances
19/01/21 03:38:44 INFO gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase: GHFS version: 1.6.10-hadoop2
19/01/21 03:38:45 WARN shortcircuit.DomainSocketFactory: The short-circuit local reads feature cannot be used because libhadoop cannot be loaded.
19/01/21 03:38:46 INFO client.ConfiguredRMFailoverProxyProvider: Failing over to rm1
19/01/21 03:38:46 INFO retry.RetryInvocationHandler: Exception while invoking getClusterMetrics of class ApplicationClientProtocolPBClientImpl over rm1 after 1 fail over attempts. Trying to fail over after sleeping for 829ms.
java.net.ConnectException: Call From mytable/ipaddress to mytable:0000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapWithMessage(NetUtils.java:792)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:732)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1479)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1412)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:229)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy15.getClusterMetrics(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.impl.pb.client.ApplicationClientProtocolPBClientImpl.getClusterMetrics(ApplicationClientProtocolPBClientImpl.java:206)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:191)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy16.getClusterMetrics(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.YarnClientImpl.getYarnClusterMetrics(YarnClientImpl.java:487)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client$$anonfun$submitApplication$1.apply(Client.scala:156)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client$$anonfun$submitApplication$1.apply(Client.scala:156)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.Logging$class.logInfo(Logging.scala:54)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.logInfo(Client.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.submitApplication(Client.scala:155)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend.start(YarnClientSchedulerBackend.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.start(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:173)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:509)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:247)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:236)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:206)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:531)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:495)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupConnection(Client.java:614)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:712)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$2900(Client.java:375)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1528)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1451)
    ... 32 more
19/01/21 03:38:46 INFO client.ConfiguredRMFailoverProxyProvider: Failing over to rm2
19/01/21 03:38:46 INFO yarn.Client: Requesting a new application from cluster with 80 NodeManagers
19/01/21 03:38:46 INFO yarn.Client: Verifying our application has not requested more than the maximum memory capability of the cluster (45056 MB per container)
19/01/21 03:38:46 INFO yarn.Client: Will allocate AM container, with 24576 MB memory including 2234 MB overhead
19/01/21 03:38:46 INFO yarn.Client: Setting up container launch context for our AM
19/01/21 03:38:46 INFO yarn.Client: Setting up the launch environment for our AM container
19/01/21 03:38:46 INFO yarn.Client: Preparing resources for our AM container
19/01/21 03:38:48 INFO yarn.Client: Uploading resource file:/opt/hadoop/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip -> hdfs://name-dataproc/user/xxxxxxx/.sparkStaging/application_1547596846411_1167/pyspark.zip
19/01/21 03:38:48 INFO yarn.Client: Uploading resource file:/opt/hadoop/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip -> hdfs://name-dataproc/user/xxxxxxx/.sparkStaging/application_1547596846411_1167/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip
19/01/21 03:38:48 INFO yarn.Client: Uploading resource file:/tmp/spark-1c0d417f-4fd6-411a-9480-0fc147d7c9a8/__spark_conf__2865868052747382300.zip -> hdfs://name-dataproc/user/xxxxxxx/.sparkStaging/application_1547596846411_1167/__spark_conf__.zip
19/01/21 03:38:48 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: xxxxxxx
19/01/21 03:38:48 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: xxxxxxx
19/01/21 03:38:48 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to: 
19/01/21 03:38:48 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to: 
19/01/21 03:38:48 INFO spark.SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(xxxxxxx); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(xxxxxxx); groups with modify permissions: Set()
19/01/21 03:38:48 INFO yarn.Client: Submitting application application_1547596846411_1167 to ResourceManager
19/01/21 03:38:48 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1547596846411_1167
19/01/21 03:38:48 INFO cluster.SchedulerExtensionServices: Starting Yarn extension services with app application_1547596846411_1167 and attemptId None
19/01/21 03:38:49 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1547596846411_1167 (state: ACCEPTED)
19/01/21 03:38:49 INFO yarn.Client: 
     client token: N/A
     diagnostics: AM container is launched, waiting for AM container to Register with RM
     ApplicationMaster host: N/A
     ApplicationMaster RPC port: -1
     queue: long_running
     start time: 1548063528733
     final status: UNDEFINED
     tracking URL: http://name-dataproc-.:0000/proxy/application_1547596846411_1167/
     user: xxxxxxx
19/01/21 03:38:50 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1547596846411_1167 (state: ACCEPTED)
19/01/21 03:38:51 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1547596846411_1167 (state: ACCEPTED)
19/01/21 03:38:52 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1547596846411_1167 (state: ACCEPTED)
19/01/21 03:38:52 INFO cluster.YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnSchedulerEndpoint: ApplicationMaster registered as NettyRpcEndpointRef(spark-client://YarnAM)
19/01/21 03:38:52 INFO cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Add WebUI Filter. org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webproxy.amfilter.AmIpFilter, 
19/01/21 03:38:53 INFO cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Application application_1547596846411_1167 has started running.
19/01/21 03:38:53 INFO util.Utils: Successfully started service 'org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService' on port 34040.
19/01/21 03:38:53 INFO netty.NettyBlockTransferService: Server created on 00.000.00.00:23930
19/01/21 03:38:53 INFO storage.BlockManager: Using org.apache.spark.storage.RandomBlockReplicationPolicy for block replication policy
19/01/21 03:38:53 INFO storage.BlockManagerMaster: Registering BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, ip-address, port, None)
19/01/21 03:38:53 INFO storage.BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager ip-address:port with 4.3 GB RAM, BlockManagerId(driver, 10.206.52.22, 46766, None)
19/01/21 03:38:53 INFO storage.BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, ip-address, port, None)
19/01/21 03:38:53 INFO storage.BlockManager: external shuffle service port = 0000
19/01/21 03:38:53 INFO storage.BlockManager: Initialized BlockManager: BlockManagerId(driver, ip-address, port, None)
19/01/21 03:38:54 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@dfsdfsdfgs{/metrics/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
19/01/21 03:38:54 INFO scheduler.EventLoggingListener: Logging events to hdfs://name-dataproc/user/spark/eventlog/application_1547596846411_1167
19/01/21 03:38:54 INFO util.Utils: Using initial executors = 8, max of spark.dynamicAllocation.initialExecutors, spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors and spark.executor.instances
19/01/21 03:38:54 INFO cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend: SchedulerBackend is ready for scheduling beginning after reached minRegisteredResourcesRatio: 0.0
19/01/21 03:38:54 INFO internal.SharedState: loading hive config file: file:/opt/hadoop/conf/hive-site.xml
19/01/21 03:38:54 INFO internal.SharedState: spark.sql.warehouse.dir is not set, but hive.metastore.warehouse.dir is set. Setting spark.sql.warehouse.dir to the value of hive.metastore.warehouse.dir ('gs://place/place/path').
19/01/21 03:38:54 INFO internal.SharedState: Warehouse path is 'gs://place/place/path'.
19/01/21 03:38:54 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@sdfsdgs{/SQL,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
19/01/21 03:38:54 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@sdfsdfs{/SQL/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
19/01/21 03:38:54 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@sdfsdf{/SQL/execution,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
19/01/21 03:38:54 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@sdfsdf{/SQL/execution/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
19/01/21 03:38:54 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@dsfgsdgd{/static/sql,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
19/01/21 03:38:55 INFO gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase: GCS Metadata Cache is enabled: this isn't necessary and in fact is probably detrimental to your job!
19/01/21 03:38:55 INFO state.StateStoreCoordinatorRef: Registered StateStoreCoordinator endpoint
19/01/21 03:38:55 INFO execution.SparkSqlParser: Parsing command: select * from mytable limit 100
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/xxxxxx/spark_job_example.py", line 8, in <module>
    df= sqlContext.sql('select * from mytable limit 100')
  File "/opt/hadoop/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/context.py", line 384, in sql
  File "/opt/hadoop/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 603, in sql
  File "/opt/hadoop/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1133, in __call__
  File "/opt/hadoop/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 69, in deco
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u"Table or view not found: `mytable`.`myttable`; line 1 pos 14;\n'GlobalLimit 100\n+- 'LocalLimit 100\n   +- 'Project [*]\n      +- 'UnresolvedRelation `mytable`.`table`\n"
19/01/21 03:38:56 INFO spark.SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
19/01/21 03:38:56 INFO server.AbstractConnector: Stopped Spark@fec850a{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:4049}
19/01/21 03:38:56 INFO ui.SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://10.206.52.22:4049
19/01/21 03:38:56 INFO cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Interrupting monitor thread
19/01/21 03:38:56 INFO cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Shutting down all executors
19/01/21 03:38:56 INFO cluster.YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnDriverEndpoint: Asking each executor to shut down
19/01/21 03:38:56 INFO cluster.SchedulerExtensionServices: Stopping SchedulerExtensionServices
(serviceOption=None,
 services=List(),
 started=false)
19/01/21 03:38:56 INFO cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Stopped
19/01/21 03:38:56 INFO spark.MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
19/01/21 03:38:56 INFO memory.MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
19/01/21 03:38:56 INFO storage.BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
19/01/21 03:38:56 INFO storage.BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped
19/01/21 03:38:56 INFO scheduler.OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint: OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
19/01/21 03:38:56 INFO spark.SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
19/01/21 03:38:56 INFO util.ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
19/01/21 03:38:56 INFO util.ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-1c0d417f-4fd6-411a-9480-0fc147d7c9a8
19/01/21 03:38:56 INFO util.ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-1c0d417f-4fd6-411a-9480-0fc147d7c9a8/pyspark-82d123ce-18ce-43ce-b631-8638bf5ffbfb
```

I appreciate any help

Comment: Where is `mytable`? It seems to be having trouble figuring out where that is. I'm curious as to how your spark shell was able to pick it up. One thing you can do is see the tables available in your catalog - do this with: `for table in spark.catalog.listTables():
  print(table)`
A refinement to your code you can do is remove the SQLContext stuff. You can execute SQL using the SparkSession directly with: spark.sql("select ....

Comment: I am running pyspark on a GCP dataproc cluster and `mytable` can be accessed with the same code above. It works in copy pasting the code, but when same code is in .py it gives the error.

Comment: Try as @Tanjin said, run `for table in spark.catalog.listTables(): print(table)` in the .py script in order to see what tables are acceded by the script.